# Fine Uploader request to S3 results in InvalidAccessKeyId error

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I have jquery fine-uploader 5.2.1 which I configured like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#fineUploader').fineUploaderS3({
          template: 'qq-template',
          request: {
              endpoint: "https://MY-BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com",
              accessKey: "MY-AWS-KEY",
          },
          signature: {
              endpoint: "/s3demo-cors.php" 
          },
          uploadSuccess: {
              endpoint: "index.html"
          },
          chunking: {
              enabled:   true,
              mandatory: true,
          }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

and I have s3demo-cors.php where I modified these two lines only

```
$clientPrivateKey = 'MY AWS SECRET KEY';
$expectedBucketName = "MY-BUCKET";
```

When examining the flow, I can see signature getting generated correctly, then OPTIONS request is successfully made but then this request is made and results in 403 InvalidAccessKeyId response from amazon.

```
POST /8fbc7973-d054-41aa-a2af-f9c9d29569f0.jpg?uploads HTTP/1.1
Host: MY-BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
x-amz-acl: private
Origin: https://MY-HOST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36 FirePHP/4Chrome
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Authorization: AWS MY-AWS-KEY:SIGNATURE
x-amz-meta-qqfilename: beautiful_scenery-1024x768.jpg
x-amz-date: Fri, 08 May 2015 15:02:58 GMT
Accept: */*
Referer: https://MY-HOST/fineuploader/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
X-Wf-Max-Combined-Size: 261120
```

I have the following in my CORS file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I am almost stuck at this point and will appreciate any insights of how I can debug this further.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Also in case it helps, for a single request, these are the headers that I am requested to sign

```
POST

image/jpeg

x-amz-acl:private
x-amz-date:Fri, 08 May 2015 15:19:52 GMT
x-amz-meta-qqfilename:beautiful_scenery-1024x768.jpg
/MY-BUCKET/bedbba49-ae0c-479d-b7a0-663bbd55cc53.jpg?uploads
```

And these the ones that are sent out

```
POST /bedbba49-ae0c-479d-b7a0-663bbd55cc53.jpg?uploads HTTP/1.1
Host: MY-BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
x-amz-acl: private
Origin: https://MY-HOST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36 FirePHP/4Chrome
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Authorization: AWS MY-KEY:SIGNATURE
x-amz-meta-qqfilename: beautiful_scenery-1024x768.jpg
x-amz-date: Fri, 08 May 2015 15:19:52 GMT
Accept: */*
Referer: https://MY-HOST/fineuploader/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
X-Wf-Max-Combined-Size: 261120
```

Comment: Are you using temporary credentials, or a "permanent" access key?

Comment: It's a permanent key+secret (i.e. no session token)

Comment: The error indicates that you are indeed using temporary credentials w/out a session token. It's very specific to the access key. So it seems as if something is not quite right with your client-side key.

Comment: I believe you are right; I went into my own AWS account and generated bucket+key+secret and everything works for those credentials; it must be something is wrong with the credentials that were provided to me. I'll try to figure it out and will post here if it ends being some interesting AWS problem.